# How to differentiate between the first keypress and subsequent keypresses in C

Tags: c

I am writing a simple program that starts to function on a key press.

It will print a message first, then prompt the user to press a key to start the process.

The first key press can be any key (including ESC), and prompts the program to loop once. It then prompts the user to press another key. If ESC is pressed, the program exits. Otherwise the program will continue looping.

What is the easiest way to achieve this in C? So far I can only make the program exit when ESC is pressed, regardless of whether if it's the first prompt or not.

Here is the general structure I have so far, sorry if my formatting is awful:

```
while(1)
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
        do 
        {
        //bunch of code//
        iKeyPress = getch();
        } while (iKeyPress != 27);
    }
}
```

The new iteration doesn't seem to end, regardless of what I press.

Comment: How do you read the key input? Please show us the code you have so far.

Comment: I've posted what I have so far. It's a little different from wrangler's approach because instead of getchar, I am using kbhit and getch.

Comment: You're missing some braces. You have 3 opening ones (`while`, `if`, `do`), but only 2 closing ones.

Comment: Lost in transcription! The syntax is correct in Visual Studio.

Comment: @darktongue when your question has different aim you should ask another one not just **edit** this may seem the provided answer is wrong.

Comment: The overall inquiry is the same though. Is there a major difference whether I wish to have a prompt before the main loop or not?

Comment: @darktongue provide whole code as its actually unclear what you want and add **edit** beneath before adding.....

Comment: What is unclear about my question? I'll try to clarify if I can. There is actually not much code outside of that loop, mostly printf so not really relevant.

Comment: After printing the prompt to press ESC again, should there be a wait for another keypress before resuming normal program execution, or should the program continue executing as if ESC had never been pressed and just exit on the next ESC keypress?

Comment: Yes, the program should prompt for another keypress after the first loop. Depending on the keypress, it will either loop again (anykey other than ESC) or return 0 (ESC).

The very first prompt along with the welcome message will read "Press any key to continue" and it should execute that message literally (acceptable keys include ESC). However, subsequent prompts for program continuation will differentiate between ESC and any other key.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
{
     getchar();  //first input
     char ch;
     do {      // will work first time irrespective of what you press        
              /*
              * rest of code
              */
              ch = getch();

        } while (ch != 27);

return 0;
}
```

EDIT:
Your code dosnt seem to work its because you have 2 loops the outer one is always true so if you manage to get out of inner loop the outer loop again iterates again.

If outer loop is important just use:

```
While(1)
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
       do {
              //bunch of code//
              iKeyPress = getch();
          } while (iKeyPress != 27);

         if(ikeyPress == 27 ) return 1;  //

    //rest of code
    }
}
```

Comment: This program won't compile with an error that `ch` in `ch != 27` isn't defined. Try defining `ch` before the loop.

Comment: The outer loop is necessary because I want to print a message before the program actually starts.

So I'll have a few messages before the loop, and afterwards the program loops and waits for the user input. I'm not sure if it's the most efficient way to go about it, but it's what I have so far. I have tried to return a value if iKeyPress is 27, but that will exit the program if the first key press is the ESC key, which I do not want.

Comment: You're right, I should put that in. Sorry about that!

Answer (score 0):

You could keep track of the number of times <kbd>ESC</kbd> has been pressed. For example:

```
int    esc_press_count    = 0;

while (esc_press_count < 2)
{
    if(kbhit())
    {
        do 
        {
        //bunch of code//
        iKeyPress = getch();
        } while (iKeyPress != 27);

        ++esc_press_count;
        if (esc_press_count < 2)
        {
            // Prompt for second ESC.
        }
    }
}
```

Whether you wait for a second ESC or continue looping, the second ESC will exit the program because `esc_press_count < 2` will be false.

Comment: Actually this was the solution I went with in the interim. Until I can come up with something more elegant it'll have to do. Thanks for your help!